# With a Progress Openedge ABL (ChUI) program what is the most efficient method to determine run time?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

To any that view this,

I am trying to determine the run time of a number of programs with a Progress Openedge ABL character based application. Initially, I started with using the etime function and logging it out as a message. However, that is very tedious as you have to reset etime within each respective block.

Shortly after this I was alerted to a method of outputting the a number of details to a custom log file. This included STRING(NOW). This helps narrow down things and makes accessing/recording the time stamps much more manageable. However, I'm curious if there's a native "method" to find the run time of each block of code that isn't so arduous?

Comment: What version of Progress are you using?  The available options can vary significantly based on the version of Progress that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main options that spring to mind are LOG-MANAGER and PROFILER.

The LOG-MANAGER is similar to what you are doing -- it writes to log files that you then analyze.  You would probably want the 4GL Trace log entry type.

PROFILER is, in my opinion, more useful.  It is better supported from a tooling perspective.  PROFILER gives you microsecond precise line by line timing.  You can use it with any release of Progress since 8.2.  There are several stand-alone analysis tools available or you can use the tooling in PDSOE (if you  have that available).  It is also not all that hard to write your own.

Both tools can be enabled with startup parameters:  LOG-MANAGER uses the -clientlog, -logentrytypes and -logginglevel startup parameters.  PROFILER is -profile (or -zprofile in v8).

Or you can turn them on/off and manipulate properties programmatically using the handles LOG-MANAGER or PROFILER within your code

Both tools have lots of kbase entries and are frequent subjects of PUG talks that go into the gory details.

Comment: This is exactly the information I was searching for and I can't thank you enough for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome.  Marking the answer as "correct"  is a nice way to say "thank you" ;)

Comment: Beware when using the profiler! While a good tool, it is like putting an ice cold thermometer into a hot turkey to check if it's cooked. 

If for example you are doing a lot of function calls, the profiler will point out that most time is in the function calls, when it is actually the profiler logging the function calls that is taking the time.

Comment: I'll be wary of that behavior @StefanDrissen

Comment: @StefanDrissen Good point! Still it can be a good way of finding problematic programs and procedures. Think of it more like "this program takes 20% of the time" rather than "this program takes 230 milliseconds".

Comment: @Jensd The problem is, that 20% of the time is skewed too - look at https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5bad012f689ac207d737507b 
            normal function
normal 57  200
profiler 386 945

which means that depending on /how/ you are are coding influences /where/ the profiler is pointing you - which is incorrect. Some years back we "improved" the performance of source identified by the profiler, only to find that the end gain when /not/ profiing (ie real world situation) was negligible.

Comment: I@StefanDrissen I guess nothing relly beats good application knowledge and excellent index usage!

Comment: Of course there are situations where it might not be ideal or where it leads to funny results but I still find it to almost always be a whole lot better than inserting MESSAGE statements willy nilly.  In fact - not too long ago I used the profiler to identify a situation where the bulk of delays in a customer system were coming from the MESSAGE statements that they were using to try to trace the application.